# What happens when you call `if key in dict`

Tags: python, hash, dictionary, equality

I have a class (let's call it `myClass`) that implements both `__hash__` and `__eq__`. I also have a `dict` that maps `myClass` objects to some value, computing which takes some time.

Over the course of my program, many (in the order of millions) `myClass` objects are instantiated. This is why I use the `dict` to keep track of those values.

However, sometimes a new `myClass` object might be equivalent to an older one (as defined by the `__eq__` method). So rather than compute the value for that object again, I'd rather just lookup the value of older `myClass` object in the `dict`. To accomplish this, I do `if myNewMyClassObj in dict`.

Here's my question:

When I use that `in` clause, what gets called, `__hash__` or `__eq__`? The point of using a `dict` is that it's O(1) lookup time. So then `__hash__` must be called. But what if `__hash__` and `__eq__` aren't equivalent methods? In that case, will I get a false positive for `if myNewMyClassObj in dict`?

Follow up question:

I want to minimize the number of entries in my `dict`, so I would ideally like to keep only one of a set of equivalent `myClass` objects in the `dict`. So again, it seems that `__eq__` needs to be called when computing `if myNewClassObj in dict`, which would defile a `dict`'s O(1) lookup time to an O(n) lookup time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `__hash__(myNewMyClassObj)` gets called. If no object with the same hash is found in the dictionary, Python assumes `myNewMyClassObj` is not in the dictionary. (Note that Python requires that whenever `__eq__` evaluates as equal for two objects, their `__hash__` must be identical.)

If some objects with the same `__hash__` are found in the dictionary, `__eq__` gets called on each of them. If `__eq__` evaluates as equal for any of them, the `myNewMyClassObj in dict_` returns True.

Thus, you just need to make sure both `__eq__` and `__hash__` are fast.

To your follow up question: yes, `dict_` stores only one of a set of equivalent `MyClass` objects (as defined by `__eq__`). (As does set.)

Note that `__eq__` is only called on the objects that had the same hash and got allocated to the same bucket. The number of such objects is usually a very small number (`dict` implementation makes sure of that). So you still have (roughly) `O(1)` lookup performance.

Answer (score 7):

`__hash__` will always be called; `__eq__` will be called if the object is indeed in the dictionary, or if another object with the same hash is in the dictionary.  The hash value is used to narrow down the choice of possible keys.  The keys are grouped into "buckets" by hash value, but for lookup Python still has to check each key in the bucket for equality with the lookup key.  See http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys .  Look at these examples:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     
...     def __hash__(self):
...         print "Hash"
...         return hash(self.x)
... 
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         print "Eq"
...         return self.x == other.x
>>> Foo(1) in d
Hash
Eq
10: True
>>> Foo(2) in d
Hash
Eq
11: True
>>> Foo(3) in d
Hash
Eq
12: True
>>> Foo(4) in d
Hash
13: False
```

In that example, you can see `__hash__` is always called.  `__eq__` is called once for each lookup when the object is in the dict, because they all have distinct hash values, so one equality check is enough to verify that the object with that hash value is indeed the one being queried.  `__eq__` is not called in the last case, because none of the objects in the dict have the same hash value as `Foo(4)`, so Python doesn't need to continue with the `__eq__`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     
...     def __hash__(self):
...         print "Hash"
...         return 1
... 
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         print "Eq"
...         return self.x == other.x
>>> d = {Foo(1): 2, Foo(2): 3, Foo(3): 4}
Hash
Hash
Eq
Hash
Eq
Eq
>>> Foo(1) in d
Hash
Eq
18: True
>>> Foo(2) in d
Hash
Eq
Eq
19: True
>>> Foo(3) in d
Hash
Eq
Eq
Eq
20: True
>>> Foo(4) in d
Hash
Eq
Eq
Eq
21: False
```

In this version, all objects have the same hash value.  In this case `__eq__` is always called, sometimes multiple times, because the hash doesn't distinguish between the values, so Python needs to explicitly check equality against all values in the dict until it finds an equal one (or finds that none of them equal the one it's looking for).  Sometimes it finds it on the first try (`Foo(1) in dict` above), sometimes it has to check all the values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I just accidentally hit save before including them, they are there now.

Comment: Python does not use buckets in its hash tables: it uses slots with each slot containing a single value. If a slot is full then it will choose another slot and so on until it finds a match or an unused slot.

Answer (score 1):

__hash__ defines the bucket the object is put into, __eq__ gets called only when objects are in the same bucket.