# How is the return value of __hash__ used?

Tags: python, hash, key

Suppose I write a class, but don't define a `__hash__` for it. Then `__hash__(self)` defaults to `id(self)` (`self`'s memory address), according to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

However I don't see in the documentation, how this value is being used.
So if my `__hash__` was simply `return 1`, which would cause the hash of all instances of my class to be the same, they all get bucketed into the same underlying hash bucket (which I assume is implemented in C). However, this does not mean that the return value of `__hash__` is being used as the key to bin elements in this underlying hash table.
So really, my question is: what happens to the value returned by `__hash__`? is it used as the key directly, or is its hash (or the result of some other computation performed on it) used as the key to the hash table?

In case it matters, I'm on python2.7

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm not asking about how hash collisions are handled. In python, [this seems to be done with linear chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001957/198633). Instead, I'm asking how the return value of `__hash__` translates into the memory address (?) of the corresponding bucket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python. Identity in sets of objects. And hashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352488/python-identity-in-sets-of-objects-and-hashing)

Comment: @BrenBarn: this is not a duplicate of that question. That question asks how hashing works and why equivalent objects are not duplicated in a set. My question is how does the output of `__hash__` translate into the memory location of the bucket in which that object is stored

Comment: I don't think that's defined by the language, as most aspects of Python aren't defined at that level of granularity.  The *behavior* is defined, as described in the post I linked to (and others mentioned there).

Comment: Also, I don't quite get what you mean by "the underlying hash table".  What underlying hash table, underlying what?  `__hash__` is only used when hashing objects (e.g., for use in a dictionary or set).  If you never use your object in a way that requires it to be hashed, it doesn't matter what its `__hash__` does.

Comment: @BrenBarn: `underlying hash bucket (which I assume is implemented in C` i.e. underlying a Python dictionary is a hash table (which has buckets), implemented in C.

Comment: Note, Python does NOT use linear chaining, it uses a particular open addressing mechanism as described by Raymond below, though I'm not sure if there's a specific name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python's hash tables have a size that is a power-of-two, the lower bits of the hash value determine the location in the hash table (or at least the location of the initial probe).

The sequence of probes into a table size of *n* is given by:

```
def gen_probes(hashvalue, n):
    'Same sequence of probes used in the current dictionary design'
    mask = n - 1
    PERTURB_SHIFT = 5
    if hashvalue < 0:
        hashvalue = -hashvalue
    i = hashvalue & mask
    yield i
    perturb = hashvalue
    while True:
        i = (5 * i + perturb + 1) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        yield i & mask
        perturb >>= PERTURB_SHIFT
```

For example, the dictionary:

```
d = {'timmy': 'red', 'barry': 'green', 'guido': 'blue'}
```

is stored as an array of size 8 with each entry in the form `(hash, key, value)`:

```
entries = [['--', '--', '--'],
           [-8522787127447073495, 'barry', 'green'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           [-9092791511155847987, 'timmy', 'red'],
           ['--', '--', '--'],
           [-6480567542315338377, 'guido', 'blue']]
```

The C source code for key insertion in Python's dictionaries can be found here:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd87afe18ff8/Objects/dictobject.c#l550

Answer (score 1):

When an object is stored in a dictionary, the `__hash__` is used to determine the original bin that the object is placed in. However, that doesn't mean one object will get confused with another in the dictionary- they still check for object equality. It just means that the dictionary will be a bit slower in hashing that type of object than others.

Comment: `the __hash__ is used to determine the original bin` <- but how? I know there's a strict one-to-one correspondence between `__hash__`'s return value and the bucket (which is basically a memory location) that the object is put into ([which seems to use linear chaining to handle collisions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13001957/198633)). But how does the int returned by `__hash__` translate into that memory address?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: `"I know there's a strict one to one"`- no, not quite. Different objects can map to the same bin- when that happens, the Python dictionary handles the collision. [This is a great summary of the Python dictionary implementation.](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/)

Comment: Honest question, if this is true, why does `{True: 'a', 1: 'b'}` evaluate to `{True: 'b'}`? (`True` and `1` both hash to `1`.)

Comment: @BrianMarshall: Nice find! Looks like it's because `True == 1`- which means the hash table is testing equality rather than identity. Two objects can return the same hash value but still not `==` each other. (A demonstration: `class Obj2(object): pass; Obj2.__hash__ = lambda s: 1;  print hash(Obj2()) == hash(Obj2()); print Obj2() == Obj2()`. The `lambda` bit is just to allow me to define it all in one line with semicolons).

Answer (score 0):

Of course logically (from the view of code that *uses* the hash table) the object itself is the key.  If you search for key `"foo"` in the hash table, no matter what other objects in the hash table have the same hash value as `"foo"`, the corresponding value will only be returned if one of the key-value pairs stored in the hash table has key equal to `"foo"`.

I don't know *exactly* what Python does, but a hash table implementation has to account for hash collisions.  If the hash table array has `N` slots, then if you insert `N + 1` values (and the table is not resized first), there must be a collision.  Also, as in the case you mentioned where `__hash__` always returns 1, or just as a quirk of the hash function implementation, it is possible to have two objects with exactly the same hash code.

There are two major strategies used to deal with hash collisions in a hash table for a single machine in memory (different techniques used for distributed hash tables, etc.):

1. Each slot in the array is a list (typically a linked list), and all values that hash to `k` modulo `N` are placed into the list at slot `k`.  So if hash values collide, that isn't a problem because both objects with the same hash value end up in the same list.
2. Some kind of probing scheme.  Basically, if the object you're inserting has hash value equal to `k` modulo `N`, you look at slot `k`.  If it's full, you apply some formula to the current location (maybe just add 1), and look at the next slot.  You follow a regular pattern to choose the next slot, given the original hash value and the number of probes so far, and keep probing until you find an open slot.  This is less used, since if you aren't careful about your implementation you can run into clustering problems i.e. have to probe many many times before finding the object.

Wikipedia talks a lot more about hash table implementations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: I have a working understanding of hashing algorithms. Please see my edit for clarification of the question