# Does anyone actually know how the order of a set is decided in Python?

Tags: python, implementation, cpython, unordered-set

There does seem to be some consistency in that calling `set()` on a string always seems to resolve to the same (non-alabetical) order, and both

```python
set([1,2,3]) & set([1,2,3,4])
```

and its jumbled up cousin

```python
set([2,3,1]) & set([4,3,1,2])
```

will result in orderly-looking `set([1,2,3])`.

On the other hand, something like a bit more racy, such as

```python
from random import randint
set([randint(0,9) for x in range(3)])
```

will sometimes give something like `set([9, 6, 7])` ...

... what is going on here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: You may find this thread interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-cpythons-set-implemented

Comment: I did some minor experimenting a while back and I think I found it to be somehow binary, like a binary search tree (but I have a feeling I'm horribly wrong here, as it's expected to behave as a hash-table). You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13001913/198633) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14493204/198633)

Answer (score 5):

You should consider sets as **unordered** collections

They are stored in a hash table.

Additionally, as you continue to add elements, the hash will be shifted into a larger table, so that order may change dramatically.

There is no guarantee that the order will be the same across different Python versions/implementations.

Comment: I just came to leave http://bugs.python.org/issue13703 here. The order being deterministic is an implementation detail that is irrelevant, all that matters is that `set` is unordered.

Comment: @mmgp, I meant to say that first, but forgot :)

Comment: I also implicitly asked to not mention the order is deterministic (see the report). For instance, start Python 3.3 and do `hash('x')`, exit the interpreter and start again, try `hash('x')` again.