# How to define "duplicate" when removing duplicate dictionaries in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

**Summary**: I have a list of dictionaries, some of the elements being "duplicated". How can I define "duplicate" and how can I influence which element stays?

**Detailed question**:

There is a [great answer to a stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090758/python-remove-duplicate-dictionaries-from-a-list) on how to remove duplicates from a list of dictionaries:

```
l = [
    {'name': 'john', 'age': 20},
    {'name': 'john', 'age': 20},
    {'name': 'mark', 'age': 21},
    {'name': 'john', 'age': 99},
    {'name': 'john'}
]
print [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in l)]
```

I would like, however, to control the definition of "duplicate". For instance let's say that any of the dictionaries which has the same value for `'name'` are "duplicates" to me. The expected output would be two elements only (one entry for `'john'` and one for `'mark'`).

I would also like to control which of the "duplicates" is retained. For instance only the one with the highest `'age'` for a given `'name'`. The pruned down list would therefore be

```
[{'age': 99, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'mark'}]
```

How can I do this in a clever and pythonic way? (my current idea is to go for a loop over the key `'name'` and set a flag (on the age in the case above) to copy the most relevant entry into a new list -- but I was hoping for something more elegant)

Comment: `set`s and `dict`s mark duplicates by objects that have the same `hash` value. If you really want control over duplication, then you should wrap these `dict`s in your own class and define a `__hash__` for that class.

Comment: when in doubt, iterate over the collection yourself and accumulate things as you need, using the tools that python gives you to make life easier.  I recommend `defaultdict` and/or `groupby`.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: would you have a pointer to some examples on how to do that? There are already very good answers below but the idea to build my own comparison is very appealing

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14493204/198633) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13001913/198633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort the list by `age`.
2. Construct a dictionary from it using `name` as key. (The choice of key "defines the duplicate".) In case of duplicate keys, the previous value is replaced. Because the list is sorted, the highest age prevails.
3. Construct again a list of dictionaries.

.

```
>>> uniq = {d['name']: d.get('age') for d in sorted(l, key=lambda d : d.get('age'))}
>>> uniq
{'john': 99, 'mark': 21}
>>> [{'name': k, 'age': v} for k, v in uniq.items()]
[{'age': 99, 'name': 'john'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'mark'}]
```